# Typescript see the one type in reqursive git submodule as different types

Tags: typescript

I have some projects with same git submodules

'ProjectA' has submodule 'ProjectB' and submodule 'ProjectC'

'ProjectB' has submodule 'ProjectC'

When I try call ProjectB.func(ProjectC.type) in ProjectA I see next error:

Type 'import("/home/merokhin/ProjectA/src/apps/ProjectB/src/ProjectC/library/sources/Crud").Crud<T, R>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/merokhin/ProjetA/src/ProjectC/library/sources/Crud").Crud<T, R>'.

But this is same types in fisical different files

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! We may need more information to answer your question. What are the type definitions for `ProjectB.func`? If you could also provide some context lines of code too, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi!
Class Crud is defined only in ProjectC and used in ProjectA. But ProjectB.func() has param type Crud and import it from ProjectB/ProjectC
Exist two files with same class:
ProjectA/ProjectC/Crud
ProjectA/ProjectB/ProjectC/Crud

Comment: Full error text when Itry build ProjectA:
`
ERROR in src/apps/ProjectB/src/ProjectC/library/sources/Crud.ts:741:48
TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Crud<T, R> | undefined'.
  Type 'import("/home/merokhin/ProjectA/src/apps/ProjectB/src/ProjectC/library/sources/Crud").Crud<T, R>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/merokhin/ProjectA/src/ProjectC/library/sources/Crud").Crud<T, R>'.
    Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'Crud<T, R>'.
  > 741 |           this.fetcher.subscribersCall(result, this)
`

Comment: Please update your answer with code to make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This isn't really related to submodules. Instead, it has to do with the type system. Suppose I import `a/b.ts` and then import `c/d.ts`. File `b.ts` declares a type named Fred, and file `d.ts` *also* declares a type named Fred. Are these two types the same type, or different types? Does it matter that the file names are `a/b.ts` and `c/d.ts`? What if the second file is named `c/b.ts`? What if it is named `c/d/b.ts`?

Comment: Typescript seems to have a rather complicated (sophisticated) method of determining type identity and compatibility. I'm not well versed in typescript (or javascript or ECMAscript) programming and don't know which systems use which ones. But ultimately the fact that project B is importing a *different version of project C* than you are means that your "project-C-version-123" things aren't "project-B's-project-C-version-456" things. Whether these different things can be *made* to work with each other is a typescript issue; and meanwhile [continued]

Comment: whether you and/or project B can agree to use a single common project-C version, instead of two different project-C versions, is a programming issue. Using a single version will solve a lot of compatibility issues, but has a price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help!
Problem was with git submodules setttings. In Webstorm default settings "recursively clone submodules in the project" is true. And it's create nested projects.

Also, for correct linting import from root submodule - you should add alterntative path in tsconfig of nested project:

```
ProjectA
|- ProjectB
|--- ProjectC
|- ProjectC
```

For correct import ProjectC to ProjectB set in ProjectB tsconfig `paths` like:

```
paths: {
  src/*: ["src/*", "../*"],
}
```